# Regex for filtering input in post field

Tags: php

The only possible value this field can have is `P` followed by a `0,1,2,3,4` and `0,1,2,3,4`

```
$option_print = $this->input->post('print');

if (!preg_match('^/p[0-4][0-4]/', $option_print)) 
{ redirect('#example'); } else { ... }
```

Example of VALID inputs:

- `p00` -> valid
- `p10` -> valid

Example of INVALID inputs:

- `v00` -> invalid
- `f10` -> invalid
- `ffs` -> invalid

So how should my `regex` be properly structured to filter for VALID inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
!preg_match('/^p[0-4][0-4]$/', $option_print)
```

Or even this:

```
!preg_match('/^p[0-4]{2}$/', $option_print)
```

Comment: Yeah that works.. I made a very simple mistake in the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: And you forgot the `$` at the end (to make sure the user input's ends with that pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost perfectly valid. But you put `^` before `/` that why it doesn't work

```
'/^p[0-4][0-4]$/'
```

Comment: yeah i realized my mistake. Thanks.